# border-radius к img

Tags: css3, border, opera, img

В Opera 10 не закругляются изображения таким способом. Пробовал обворачивать в `div` и задавать `div`'у радиусы, но всё мимо. Однако закругляется всё, кроме пикч.

```
<style type="text/css">
#attaches img {
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
</style>
<div id="attaches">
 <img src="img1.png">
 <img src="img2.png">
</div>
```

Comment: обнови оперу.В новых версиях уже работает.

Comment: @koza4ok, чувак. Никогда не думай, что все сидят с обновленными браузерами. Никогда.

Comment: Для старых браузеров - старый дизайн. Так что забей

Comment: @Саша Осипов, забил ещё в 2012 :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно картинку вставить в блочный элемент задним фоном. 100% будет круглять :-)

Comment: @lampa, а ведь правда! Очередной раз помогли! Спасибо ^.^

Answer (score 0):

У меня Ваш код работает: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/BUmz5/1/)